# Application Insights end-to-end multi component logging in Azure Functions

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

End-to-end logging between multiple components using Application Insights (AI) is based on a [hierarchical `Request-Id`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/HierarchicalRequestId.md) header. So each component is responsible to honer a possible incoming `Request-Id`. To get the full end-to-end hierarchical flow correct in Application Insights the `Request-Id` header needs to be used as the AI `Operation.Id` and `Operation.ParentId` (as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/application-insights-correlation)).

But when making a request with a `Request-Id` header to a Azure Function using a `HttpTrigger` binding for example (`Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.24`) with integrated Application Insights configured (as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/04/06/azure-functions-application-insights/)) a completely new `Operation.Id` is created and used - causing the whole flow in AI to be lost. **Any ideas on how to get around this?**

Setting up a separate custom `TelemetryClient` might be an option. But seems to require a lot of configuration to get the full `ExceptionTrackingTelemetryModule` and `DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule` right - especially when using Functions v2 and Core (ref to [AI config](https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/application-insights/app-insights-configuration-with-applicationinsights-config.md)). Anyone go that successfully working?

Comment: Can you set the incoming `Request-Id` as the `Operation.ParentId` ? Btw interesting question, I will have to do the same soon so wiating for any answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not yet supported by Functions but should start working sometime early next year.

If you want to hack it through, you can add a reference to ApplicationInsights SDK for AspNetCore (v 2.4.1) and configure RequestTrackingTelemetryModule.

```
    static Function1()
    {
        requestModule = new RequestTrackingTelemetryModule();
        requestModule.Initialize(TelemetryConfiguration.Active);

    }

    private static RequestTrackingTelemetryModule requestModule;
```

This is pretty sketchy, not fully tested and has drawbacks. E.g. request collected is no longer augmented with functions details (invocation id, etc). To overcome it you need to get the real TelemetryConfiguration from the Function dependency injection container and use it to initialize the module.
It should be [possible](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/759#issuecomment-426687852), but is blocked by [some issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3731).

But even with the code above, you should get requests that respect incoming headers and other telemetry correlated to the request.

Also, when out-of-the-box support for correlation for http request is rolled out, this may break. So this is a hacky temporary solution, use it only if you absolutely have to.

Comment: Thanks for valuable info! 

When this change will be rolled out - will it then also be possible to add custom properties to the AI tracking messages? A common requirement is to add part of the payload to the tracking, or at least a reference to where the stored payload can be found.

Comment: Just making sure you get the notification for the comment @liudmila ;)

Comment: adding custom properties will be possible once [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3731) is fixed via custom [ITelemetryInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer).

Comment: so how do we do this today?